# In Symfony 2 / Doctrine 2, can you change the inheritance at runtime (i.e. add a class)?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, decorator

Imagine a Symfony 2 bundle **A** defining the following hierarchy:

```
/** 
 * @ORMTable(name="animal")
 * @ORMInheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORMDiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="integer")
 * @ORMDiscriminatorMap({1 = "Cat", 2 = "Dog"}) 
 */
class Animal { /**/ }

/** 
 * @ORMEntity 
 */
class Cat extends Animal {  /**/ }

/** 
 * @ORMEntity 
 */
class Dog extends Animal { /**/ }
```

Bundle **B** may, in some way (for example listening to `postLoad` event), change the hierarchy adding a `Horse` class?

Why? I was looking at the [Persisting the Decorator Pattern](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/decorator-pattern.html). It's a good pattern but it's useless when you think that bundle **A** defines the decorators and won't allow bundle **B** to add new decorators because the hierarchy is defined *statically* using annotations.

Comment: *change the hierarchy adding a `Horse` class* Does it conform to the Decorator pattern ? Is `Horse` defined in your code and is added and stored in a database?

Comment: @A.L do not focus on *names*. Look at ctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/decorator-pattern.html and the way a bundle can extend the hierarchy adding a new decorator (which **is** persisted).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this bundle, it might be exactly what you're looking for:
https://packagist.org/packages/netpositive/discriminatormap-bundle
Basically it allows you to leave the DiscriminatorMap annotation empty and fill it in your configuration.